# How to use $mysqli on different files

Tags: php, file, mysqli

When I try to use $mysqli, it seems that $mysqli is not working on the function.php? How is that? And how to fix the problem?

```
<?php
    session_start();
    include "data/connect.php";
?>

<html>
  <head>
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form action="function.php" method="POST">
    Please input model: <input type="text" name="model" /> <input type="submit"/>
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

Here is the function.php:

```
<?php

    $model = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST["model"]);
    $input = $mysqli->query("INSERT INTO item (model_name) VALUES('$model')");
?>
```

Database:

```
<?php

    define('db_host','localhost');
    define('db_user','root');
    define('db_password','password');
    define('db_database','inventory');

    $mysqli = new mysqli(db_host,db_user,db_password,db_database) or die(mysql_error());
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Include the connect file on the function.php file. When you are processing the form it leaves the page you are on currently that creates the mysqli object.

Make the functions.php file as follows:

```
<?php
include('data/connect.php');

$model = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST["model"]);
$input = $mysqli->query("INSERT INTO item (model_name) VALUES('$model')");
?>
```

Comment: thank you for the reply, I saw some tutorials that they use database connection on the index, and other included files don't have duplicate include to attach database file, how is that work? I saw them use function, but I am not really trying it so far, using regular way.

Comment: Your form isn't acting as an included file to the index. When you submit the form it leaves the index and goes to the function.php file

Comment: hi, do you have any ideas or reference link that can have example to make a form processing and staying on the index without adding one more time database file? appreciate the help.

Comment: use the index.php as the form processing file. Add an if(isset($_POST['submit']){ //Form Process Stuff }  -- Just make sure it is below where you included the DB file

Answer (score 0):

in functions.php

write the code as:

```
<?php
    require_once 'database.php';
    $model = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST["model"]);
    $input = $mysqli->query("INSERT INTO item (model_name) VALUES('$model')");
?>
```

you forgot to include the database.php in functions.php file.

I hope this helps you.

Comment: try to use your method, and result is blank, mysql do not insert any new data, any other codes wrong, can you help me find out the wrong code that maybe existing on the other files, thx